# Is there difference between tensorflow slim layer and tensorflow manually built layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there any difference between tensorflow slim layer and manually built layer?
For example, the below codes are different?

1. Tensorflow slim

   ```
   output = slim.fully_connected(model_input, 1024, 
   activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_regularizer=None,
   weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
   ```
2. Manually built layer

   ```
   W1 = tf.get_variable(name='W1', shape=[1024, 1024], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
   b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))
   output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(model_input, W1) + b1)
   ```

I thought that these two are exactly same, but in the training, they showed different performance..

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "different performance"? Is it a slight difference (which would be normal)?

Comment: @ma3oun The performance is not slightly different. The loss of manual built layer is 1.5 times bigger than slim layer (for complex and big data). But.. after I posted the question, I tested the simple data (MNIST) and I got the similar performance from both layers... So I think maybe the problem is not about slim or manual built layer.. maybe the optimizer or loss calculation may be wrongly applied to manual built layer. Anyway, thanks for your attention :-)